# Declare "MUL key" field in python. (django framework)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a column which should be **MUL key**, but I couldn't find out how I can do that. Here's the code:

```
class table(models.Model):
    field2 = Models.int(max_length=9, null= False, default = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-unique indexes are [defined in the metadata options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#indexes) for the model.

```
class Table(models.Model):
   ...
  class Meta:
    indexes = [
      models.Index(fields=['field2'])
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

MUL keys are simply non-unique indexes (other index types are PRI for Primary Key and UNI for Unique, which are both unique indexes. You can add a non-unique index to any field using the `db_index` argument:

```
field2 = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0, db_index=True)
```

PS: I assume that the code in the question has a typo and you actually meant `IntegerField` and not `int`. Also, `max_length` has no effect when used with `IntegerField`s.